# Weapon Preference - Explore Mode

Tags: fallout-shelter

[image]

I have my dweller, Billy Grant, equipped with Tactical Junk Jet (15-19) exploring the wasteland. Along the way, he found a Plasma Rifle (17-18) and equip it himself --putting aside his TJJ. I wonder what is the logic for weapon preference? As I have always thought, it is the maximum number of damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Dweller will automatically equip a weapon with a higher damage output.

Comparing the two weapons:

- TJJ: 15-19 = 17 average
- Plasma Rifle: 17-18 = 17.5 average

Hence the strange choice of weaponry

Comment: average damage instead of maximum damage --that figures.

Comment: The average damage is what is used during exploration, so it won't hurt you.  In Quest Zones, you want the Plasma Rifle because it is 3 shots vs the single big damage shot from the Junk Jet.